# Recyclerview keep scrolling position after changing layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am using recycle view in my application. I have one button above recycle view in relative layout for changing layout manager. It first displays grid layout manager and when a button is clicked it displays Linearlayoutmanager. While I am changing layout manager, recycle view again starts from the first position.

Can anyone help me to keep the position as it is when making the change in layout manager dynamically?

Comment: Did you try `RecyclerView#scrollToPosition(int position)`?

Comment: I don't want to show scrolling

Comment: scrollToPosition does not show scrolling. This method name is bit complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remember the `firstVisibleItem` and scroll to that position after changing the LayoutManager it works fine I just tried it out by myself:

E.g. `Button` click to change `LayoutManager`:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               int i = ((LinearLayoutManager) rcView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
               if(rcView.getLayoutManager() instanceof GridLayoutManager) {                  
                   rcView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
               } else {                     
                   rcView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 3));   
               }
               rcView.scrollToPosition(i);
           }
       });
```

Comment: Thanks @david this answer is helpful